# WPF menu height is limited by windows task bar

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF menu in my application (not a context menu). When I change the size of my task bar in windows 7 to 4 rows for example, the menu opens with height limited to the the top of the task bar - although my application is a full window application.
how can I set the menu to take the size it requires regardless of windows task bar?

thanks...

Comment: Please provide some sample code to better understand your problem.

Comment: I don't know, but why would you have such long menus? It'll just confuse your users.

Comment: Its actually not that long - Its a touch screen so naturally all elements are bigger. menu opens with about 10 submenus items...

Answer (score 0):

Bind it to the :

- Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
- Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width

Comment: The working area is the desktop area of the display, excluding taskbars, docked windows, and docked tool bars. This property return a Rectangle. You will get the Width & Height. YEs, you can bind it to your MaxHeight property

Comment: thanks, but my problem is the opposite - I need my menu to be unaware of working area and grow as much as it needs, not limited to taskbar height...